# Remove volume indicator

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

Obviously a minor annoyance, but is there any way to remove or alter the size of the volume icon that pops up in the middle of the screen when adjusting the volume? Currently it's huge and I have to wait a few seconds for it to disappear before I can continue working!

I am aware that I can adjust the CSS of pretty much anything, but just unsure where I can adjust this particular element.

Answer (score 4):

You may use a GNOME shell extension called "[Better OSD](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1345/better-osd/)".

It lets you customise the position, size and hide delay of OSD pop-ups (including the on-screen volume indicator overlay).

[image]
(screenshot source: extension's homepage at extensions.gnome.org)

If you set the "Hide Delay" to 0 you practically won't  see the overlay at all.

Comment: Better OSD does not currently work with newer versions of Gnome, i.e. 3.30

Answer (score 0):

[Just Perfection](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3843/just-perfection/) extension can do it

[image]